# Is there a more efficient way of reading from stdin and tokenizing than allocating a large buffer and using string_view?

Tags: c++, string, performance, stdin

I'm reading a file from `stdin` and just need to run through it as fast as possible and do some processing on each of the delimited tokens.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <string_view>

namespace {
  constexpr auto BUFFER_SIZE = 25*1024*1024; // 25MiB
  std::array<char, BUFFER_SIZE> g_buf;
}

inline void process_line(std::string_view line, const char delim = '|') {
  size_t delim_pos = 0, field_start = 0;
  while (delim_pos = line.find_first_of(delim, field_start)) {
    // TODO: process field

    field_start = delim_pos + 1;
    if (delim_pos == std::string::npos) {
      break;
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
  std::cin.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(g_buf.data(), g_buf.size());
  std::string line;
  while(std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
    process_line(line);
  }
}
```

For additional context, I'm building out test implementations to compare a C++ solution vs a python solution. These test solutions need to read hundreds of TBs of compressed data (hopefully quickly) and do some transformations. Previous implementation against a similar type of file was in python and was overly complex/slow. I'm looking to split out the decompression using a linux utility like bzcat or zcat and piping into the above implementation. I'm basically doing something like below if the line matches a condition:

```
import sys

delim = '|'
for line in sys.stdin:
  tokens = delim.split(line)
  // TODO: process tokens
```

If the line matches I'll either be storing it and transforming (want to avoid because of memory usage), or throwing it back out on `stdout` in a different format to be written to disk or re-compress

I've added another implementation below which also reads from stdin but uses the linux `read` into a defined buffer as suggested in the comments (although it can probably be simplified):

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstring>
#include <array>
namespace {
  constexpr size_t BUFFER_SIZE = 1024*1024*1024; // 1GiB
  std::array<char, BUFFER_SIZE> g_buf;
}
int main() {
  void * ptr = reinterpret_cast<void *>(g_buf.data());
  ssize_t bytes_read = 0;
  size_t offset = 0, total_valid_bytes = 0;

  while(offset = reinterpret_cast<const char *>(ptr) - g_buf.data(),
        bytes_read = read(STDIN_FILENO, ptr, g_buf.size() - offset),
        total_valid_bytes = offset + bytes_read,
        bytes_read > 0) {
    size_t line_start = 0, line_end = 0;
    std::string_view read_buf(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(g_buf.data()), total_valid_bytes);

    // process each line
    while(line_end = read_buf.find_first_of('\n', line_start), line_end != std::string_view::npos) {
      std::string_view line(read_buf.data() + line_start, line_end - line_start);
      // TODO: process line
      // std::cout << line << std::endl;
      line_start = line_end + 1;
    }

    if (line_end == std::string_view::npos) {
      size_t line_frag_size = total_valid_bytes - line_start;
      std::memcpy(g_buf.data(), g_buf.data() + line_start, line_frag_size); // compact
      ptr = g_buf.data() + line_frag_size;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: First, you're using actual optimization with your compiler?  Second, you've actually profiled your code and determined where the performance bottlenecks are?  Or are you assuming you can look at your code and make it faster just from visual inspection?

Comment: performance + file generally equals memory mapped file

Comment: What are your requirements regarding the "efficiency"? Why does your code need to be more "efficient"?

Comment: I just need to run through couple hundreds of TB of compressed data, but don't want to go through the hassle of baking the decompression in. So the plan is to just bzcat or zcat the data into stdin and run through it. Can also try it in python but wanted to also make a C++ implementation to compare against

Comment: Is the whole line needed for the transformantion? If you can read it a few1 char at a time you will not need a lot of memory (like you want to put "()"-s araund every "XYZ" short substring)

Comment: I do need to go through the entire line if it matches a condition e.g. first char indicates type

Comment: @AndrewHenle I'm building out a reference implementation to compare with other options e.g. python script. I just want to make sure I'm not going about it in a poor way

Comment: @NathanOliver this would probably be the fastest option or just doing a straight read with advice set to sequential but is there a way to do this with decompressing a file without baking the decompression in?

Comment: By using anonymous pipes the uncompressed data should not be on disk, but buffered in memory. I would then use the unbuffered OS-specific functions to read directly from the standard input file handle (using `read` with `FILENO_STDIO` on POSIX systems like Linux or macOS), to read a window of data into your own buffer. Use a string view for each line, and for the last line in the buffer fetch more data from standard input. Relatively simple, and should be quick enough for most cases. Try something like that, and measure/benchmark with some example data (not the full data-set).

Comment: `25MiB` isn't that big of a buffer. Also, you could try just read a massive amount of data into a large buffer using `std::istream::read` and scan it directly for delimiters rather than reading into a `std::string`and creating a `std::string_view`for every line.

Comment: As for the splitting of the lines, will each line have the same number of fields? Then perhaps a `std::array` of `std::string_view` for each field, that can be used for further processing. Actually, instead of extracting lines from your internal buffer, create this array while scanning over the buffer to lines. One pass over the data less. Also, when benchmarking and measuring, remember to build with optimizations enabled.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude unfortunately not every line will have the same number of fields so I can't rely on that. As for the OS-specific functions, is there much difference between those and the `std::getline` call against `std::cin` with a large buffer set? I originally started off with the approach you're describing but didn't want to deal with implementing a buffered reader myself (didn't think it would add that much overhead)

Comment: Is there a max number of elements in each line? Then you can still use an array and a counter variable. Much better than a vector that needs to be resized (unless you can "guess" the number of elements and then preallocate memory).

Comment: As for `std::cin` and `std::getline`, remember that `std::cin` is buffered, adding another layer of buffering that isn't really needed. And `std::getline` will add effectively a separate pass over the data in its attempt to find the end of the line. By using the OS functions you skip one layer of buffering. And by using your own (combined) extraction and splitting, you can get all the fields of a line in a single scan over the data.

Comment: that does make sense, is the main strategy for handling the last line (when it's split across reads)  for the subsequent read, just set the ptr to the buffer where the last line left off and decrement the size by the remaining buffer size?

Comment: I would just move it "up" to the beginning of the buffer, and then (as you say) continue where you left of, filling the same buffer again (but a few bytes less because of the partial line). Even if a single line is several thousand of characters it still will be pretty quick.